# Prettifying headings in sublists

Tags: formatting, lists

I am putting together a list of exam questions, and I would like to group some of these questions because they share a common topic (for example, they are about different parts of a proof of a large theorem). However, many of the questions don't fall in any of the groups.

Here is my current document: https://www.overleaf.com/read/vbtrwmsnstvm

The text is in Russian, but that should not be a problem because I'd like to improve the formatting, not the contents. There are several blocks which look like this:

[image: screenshot]

This is how I made it:

```
\begin{compactenum}
    % ...
    \item Второй критерий корректности (управляемость) линейно-квадратичной задачи оптимального управления на бесконечном интервале времени и его обоснование, вместе с обоснованием критерия управляемости.

    \medskip\hspace{-2.00em}
    Линейно-квадратичная задача оптимального управления на бесконечном интервале времени.

    \begin{compactenum}[1.]
        \setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}
        \item Матричное уравнение Лурье-Рикатти, стабилизирующее решение.
        \item Формулировка основного результата.
        \item Доказательство основного результата: сведение к задаче на минимум квадратичной нормы на множестве решений линейного уравнения $Q(x) \to \min$, $x \in X \colon T x = y$.
        \item Доказательство основного результата в части, касающейся выводов из тотальной разрешимости задачи.
        \item Доказательство основного результата в части, касающейся выводов из существования стабилизирующего решения уравнения Лурье-Рикатти.
        \item Доказательство основного результата в части, касающейся формул для оптимального процесса.
        \item Частотное условие, доказательство необходимости.
        \item Частотное условие, доказательство достаточности.
    \end{compactenum}

    \medskip
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}

    \item Постановка задачи линейного оптимального оценивания.
    % ...
\end{compactenum}
```

I don't like the way it looks. Specifically, I don't like the way long lines aren't aligned with their beginnings (see items 45 and 47). Furthermore, I think the headings should be more distinct from the surrounding text, but I'm not sure how exactly.

1. How can I align lines with their beginnings?
2. How can I make this text prettier?
3. Can I simplify the code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler code with `enumitem`, which has a `resume` option for lists:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english ,russian,]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb} % amssymb also loads amsfonts
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titling}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace} \usepackage{enumitem} \newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}
\newcommand\questionshead{\item[\indent]\hspace*{0.7\leftmargin}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\title{Теоретическая кибернетика. Программа экзамена}
\subtitle{Матмех СПбГУ, поток математиков, 4 курс}
\author{Алексей Серафимович Матвеев}

\date{13\textsuperscript{ème} Messidor, CCXXIV | 30 июня 2016}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{wide=0pt, widest=99, leftmargin=*, noitemsep}
\begin{enumerate}%[wide=0pt, widest=99, leftmargin=*, noitemsep]
    \item Пример постановки задачи оптимального управления: задача оптимального успокоения гармонического осциллятора.
    \item Пример решения задачи оптимального управления (без обоснования): задача оптимального успокоения гармонического осциллятора.
    \item Общая постановка задачи оптимального управления системой, описываемой обыкновенным дифференциальным уравнением.
    \item Классический метод вариаций и проблемы, связанные с его применением к задачам оптимального управления.
    \item Пучок кривых (вариаций), липшицев пучок кривых, конический пучок кривых, производная по пучку кривых.
    \item "Пучковые" необходимые условия экстремума (безусловная оптимизация и оптимизация с ограничениями в виде неравенств).
    \item Пучок классических вариаций, дифференцирование по нему, связанные с ним необходимые условия экстремума.
    \item Пучок анизотропных вариаций, дифференцирование по нему, связанные с ним необходимые условия экстремума.
    \item Стандартные метрические пространства управлений, метрика Экланда.
    \item Пучки простых и сложных игольчатых вариаций.
    \item Дифференцирование по пучку сложных игольчатых вариаций.
    \item Задача А.А. Ляпунова и необходимые условия экстремума в этой задаче (теорема А.А. Ляпунова).
    \item Постановка абстрактной задачи оптимального управления и связанные с ней понятия. Общий план вывода необходимых условий оптимальности в абстрактной задаче оптимального управления без дополнительных ограничений.
    \item Теорема о неявной функции.
    \item Определение сложной функции и понятия, необходимые для её исследования: множитель Лагранжа, Лагранжиан, абстрактное сопряжённое уравнение. Лемма о разрешимости абстрактного сопряжённого уравнения.
    \item Разложение и дифференцирование сложной функции.
    \item Необходимые условия оптимальности в абстрактной задаче оптимального управления.
\end{enumerate}
%%%
\begin{enumerate}[resume*, wide=0.7\leftmargini]
\item[\indent]\hspace*{-\leftmargini} Принцип максимума Понтрягина для системы, описываемой обыкновенными дифференциальными уравнениями:
        \item постановка задачи и её нормализация.
        \item проверка условий абстрактной теоремы.
        \item расшифровка абстрактных необходимых условий оптимальности.
        \item доказательство в случае неограниченного множества допустимых управлений $\Omega$.
        \item в случае фиксированного начального и конечного состояния.
    \end{enumerate}
%%%
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*, wide=0.7\leftmargini]
\item[\indent]\hspace*{-0.9\leftmargini}
Оптимальное управление и вариационное исчисление:
        \item условия Вейерштрасса-Эрдманна.
        \item уравнение Эйлера и условие Лежандра.
        \item условие Вейерштрасса.
    \end{enumerate}
%%%
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item Общая постановка задачи оптимального управления с дискретной моделью времени. Понятие тотально разрешимой задачи.
\end{enumerate}
%%%
\begin{enumerate}[resume*, wide=0.7\leftmargini, leftmargin=*]
\item[\indent]\hspace*{-0.9\leftmargini}Метод динамического программирования:
        \item функция Беллмана и принципы динамического программирования.
        \item уравнение динамического программирования.
        \item понятия регулятора, оптимального регулятора, нахождение оптимального регулятора с помощью уравнения динамического программирования.
        \item критерий тотальной разрешимости задачи. Конечный интервал времени.
        \item критерий тотальной разрешимости задачи. Бесконечный интервал времени.
    \end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item Псевдо-обратный оператор Мура-Пенроуза и его простейшие свойства.
\end{enumerate}
%%%
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*, wide=0.7\leftmargini, leftmargin=*]
\item[\indent]\hspace*{-0.9\leftmargini}Задача частичной минимизации квадратичной нормы:
        \setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}
        \item формулировка основного результата.
        \item доказательство основного результата.
        \item следствие из основного результата лемма о минимуме квадратичной нормы на множестве решений линейного уравнения $Q(x) \to \min$, $x \in X \colon T x = y$.
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]